# Is there a way to make a error message loop?

Tags: c#

I tried to loop the error message which was catch but it only looped for one time, crashing right after I tried it again with a invalid input error even though I created the boolean error specifically for that.

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
   Console.Clear();
   bool error = false;
    try {
    Console.Write("Enter your age: ");
    int age  = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
  }
  catch{
    Console.Clear();
    error = true;
    Console.Write("\nPlease enter a valid age...\n");
  while(error == true){
    Console.Write("\n" + "Enter your age: ");
    int age  = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    if(age < 2000 && age > 0){
      error = false;
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: You should look into [`int.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8) as its more graceful and does away with the exception handling in your code.

Comment: Your second check was not in catch block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't *validate* user input with *Exceptions* when you can *parse* the input

```
int age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Instead use `TryParse` style methods to validate input for primitive *built-in data types* e.g [`int.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8).

> Converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed
>   integer equivalent. A return value indicates whether the operation
>   succeeded.

The following example parses the `Console.ReadLine` (*user input*), and *loops* until the user gets it right.

```
int age;
Console.Write("Enter your age: ");
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out age) || age > 2000 || age < 0)
   Console.Write("You had one job, enter an age, try again ");

Console.WriteLine(age);
```

<sub>***Note*** : This is not intended to be a complete working solution to your application, it's just an example of how you might validate integers without exceptions.</sub>

Comment: @RufusL you have saved people from being maimed and injured :)

Comment: Well i'm still learning... I started coding C# yesterday :) I also dont want people to be maimed or injured

Comment: indeed TryParse() is better for exception errors it worked fine, thanks :)

Comment: The handling of the [2000 Year Old Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2000_Year_Old_Man) is compromised by [East Asian age reckoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_Asian_age_reckoning).